# Magento design possible in all pages?

Tags: magento

i want to change design in my magento project. I know how to change design in home page .Is it possible to make changes in other pages...Does any one help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core templates that will be applied to most of your website are found in /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/page/html/

All of the rest just get in more detail from there, depending on what type of page you are looking at.  All of your category and product templates will be in /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/

It is pretty straight-forward, though some stuff like pricing and product types get confusing quickly to someone that hasn't done a lot of templating with Magento yet.  Essentially though, you can change pretty much anything you want.

People would be able to help you further if you asked more specific questions.  Your question is quite vague.

Answer (score 1):

Magento design is not a programming problem and does not belong on StackOverflow, but to answer your question, [yes, you can change the design of the entire store](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide) in Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

Magento has a full skinning system, as well as a complex layout/template language that's deeper than some programming languages I've worked with.